# Why does {} == {} return false?

Tags: javascript

I was writing a script, and I had something like

```
var myObject = {};

if (myObject == {}){
    ...
}
```

I was surprised to find that this evaluated to false.

### My own findings

Reading up on some of the funny querks javascript does, I found [this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/), which tells that `{}` will result in a "truthy" object in an if statement, for example

```
if ({}){ // true
    ...
}
```

Hm, well further ready discuesses String Equality, which for object comparison, says it will return true if they **reference** the same object. (Even `{} === {}` returns false)

The only reason I can think that is would return false is that the objects are technically at different memory address, and thus considered different objects.

Comment: And your last sentence is the answer

Comment: You've bolded the wrong word, which is the key to your misunderstanding.  *"it will return true if they **reference** the same object"*  should say *it will return true if they reference the **same** object.*

Comment: You know this is not a question, right?  In any case...  I think a good explanation is that an object cannot equal another object.  If you had 2 oranges that were the same, it doesn't mean they are the same orange.

Comment: Think of each instance of those brackets as "MyObject myObj = new MyObject();" in a static language. Easy way of thinking of it.

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Dont' you remember, Jacob, was this post closed as duplicate before? I was pretty sure it was but strangely appears that it wasn't...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because every `{}` creates a unique object. You can't compare them that way.

Comment: you've beaten me to it :D

Comment: I generally wouldn't recommend using `JSON.stringify` to compare objects. It will strip out functions and do other things to non-JSON types. Observe `JSON.stringify({r:/r/}) == JSON.stringify({r:{}})`

Comment: Using `.stringify` an unfortunate way to compare objects in general. I'd certainly not call it "right". In addition to what @p.s.w.g described, there's no guarantee that order of keys would be identical.

Comment: @p.s.w.g ok, i removed it. what would you suggest?

Comment: @nicael test the things you *really* care about. e.g. if you want to know that the object is empty, you might use `Object.keys({}).length == 0`

Comment: @RobinVanPersi if you want to have a nick like the footballer, you should use "Robin van Persie" :)